# Better way to select a matching subset of rows?

Tags: postgresql, optimization, array, many-to-many

[DB Fiddle link.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bfVUcS6A2592br1VEBidyj/0) I have a many to many table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE house_to_cats (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  house_id INTEGER,
  cat_id INTEGER
);

-- house with cats 1 and 2: too small
INSERT INTO house_to_cats (house_id, cat_id) VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2);
-- house with cats 1 2 3 4: too big
INSERT INTO house_to_cats (house_id, cat_id) VALUES (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4);
-- house with cats 1 2 3: just right
INSERT INTO house_to_cats (house_id, cat_id) VALUES (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3);
```

I need a query that takes an arbitrary list of cats and returns a matching house if exists. I came up with this:

```
SELECT
    house_id
FROM (
    SELECT
          house_id
        , ARRAY_AGG(cat_id) as cat_id_agg
    FROM house_to_cats
    JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT
              house_id
        FROM house_to_cats
        JOIN (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(ARRAY[1, 2, 3]) cat_id) inn USING (cat_id)
    ) filter USING (house_id)
    GROUP BY house_id
) agg
WHERE cat_id_agg <@ ARRAY[1, 2, 3]
  AND cat_id_agg @> ARRAY[1, 2, 3];
```

Is there a better way to do this?

The idea behind my query: in `filter`, get the `house_id` which have at least one of our cat in them. In `agg`, create `cat_id_agg` arrays for all of those `house_ids`. And in the outermost query filter out groups that don't match our set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, your query can be simplified to:

```
select house_id
from house_to_cats
group by house_id
having array_agg(cat_id order by cat_id) = array[1,2,3]
```

Note the `order by` in the `array_agg()` call - the array `[3,2,1]` is not equal the array `[1,2,3]`. To avoid incorrect results due to the aggregation being done in a different order, the aggregated array has to contain the values in the same order as the comparison value.

Online example: https://rextester.com/IKGHWL59301